# ColorAnimation does not like me using a DynamicResource in my WPF xaml file

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

certain key colour in my application are loaded as dynamic resources. This works fine is most controls except ColorAnimation. For this, it throws an exception:

> Cannot convert the value in attribute 'To' to object of type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Windows.Media.Color, PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]'. '#FF93CF65' is not a valid value for property 'To'.

I use exactly the same resource in the style and it works fine in that case. The xaml in question is shown below:

```xml
<Style x:Key="ChildWindowButtonBarButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonBorder}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#ffffb14c" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.8"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To=".5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.4"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From=".5" To="1" />
                        <ColorAnimation  BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.2"   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Green"/>
                        <ColorAnimation  BeginTime="00:00:00.3" Duration="00:00:00.4"   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{StaticResource ButtonBorder}"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on this?
- Dave

Answer (score 5):

I just tried it and this works

```
<Color x:Key="ButtonBorderColor">Green</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorder" Color="{StaticResource ButtonBorderColor}" />

<Style x:Key="ChildWindowButtonBarButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonBorder}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#ffffb14c" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:04"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To=".5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:04" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From=".5" To="1" />
                        <!--<ColorAnimation  BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:02" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Green"/>-->
                        <ColorAnimation  BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:04" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{StaticResource ButtonBorderColor}"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to http://objectmix.com/csharp/733011-wpf-using-storyboards-custom-control.html and a few hours of random experimentation, I have come to the conclusion that this can not be done. Not easily, at last.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set a Color value with a Brush property.  Try changing

```
<ColorAnimation  BeginTime="00:00:00.3" Duration="00:00:00.4"   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{StaticResource ButtonBorder}"/>
```

to:

```
<ColorAnimation  BeginTime="00:00:00.3" Duration="00:00:00.4"   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush)" To="{StaticResource ButtonBorder}"/>
```

Comment: Nope, no joy. I did find another article (http://objectmix.com/csharp/733011-wpf-using-storyboards-custom-control.html) that seems to state that it is by-design and not easily worked around. As such, I am closing this question.